# DoesNotExist: Group matching query does not exist

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get the details of authors with the id of the author using a librarians group.i have also included it in settings.py file and set up the group in postgresql db.Buy some group matching query does not exist is showing up while i am running the server.

directory structure:

```
untitled2

 librarymanage

  library
   decorators
     __init__.py
     group_required.py
   migrations
   static
     css
     js
   templatetags
     __init__.py
     has_group.py
     xextends.py
 __init__.py
 admin.py
 apps.py
 forms.py
 models.py
 tables.py
 tests.py
 urls.py
 validators.py
 views.py


 librarymanage

   __init__.py

   settings.py

   urls.py

   wsgi.py

  templates

    authors.html

    authors_show.html

    base.html

    books.html

    change_password.html

    periods.html

    periods_show.html

    publisher_show.html

    publishers.html

    sign_in.html

    sign_up.html


    table_without_footer.html

 db.sqlite3

 manage.py

 venv
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .forms import *

from .models import Book, LendPeriods, Author, Publisher, UserProfile

from .tables import BookTable, BookTableUser, AuthorTable, 
 PublisherTable,
 PeriodsTable

from django_tables2 import RequestConfig

from django.contrib import messages

from django.utils import timezone

from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

from .decorators.group_required import group_required

from django.db.models.base import ObjectDoesNotExist

from .templatetags import has_group

from django.http import HttpResponse

@login_required(login_url='/sign_in/')

def authors_show(request, author_id):

 try:
    author = Author.objects.get(id=author_id)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    messages.error(request, "This author does not exist")
    return redirect('/')

if author:
    books_qs = Book.objects.filter(author=author_id)
    books_table = BookTable(books_qs)
    RequestConfig(request, paginate={"per_page": 5}).configure(books_table)

    return render(request, 'authors_show.html',
                  {'author': author,
                   'books_table': books_table,
                   'books_qs': books_qs,
                   })
else:
    messages.info(request, "Author does not exist")
    return authors(request)


@login_required(login_url='/sign_in/')

def publishers_show(request, publisher_name):

try:
    publisher = Publisher.objects.get(name=publisher_name)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    messages.error(request, "This publisher does not exist")
    return redirect('/')

if publisher:
    books_qs = Book.objects.filter(publisher=publisher_name)
    books_table = BookTable(books_qs)
    RequestConfig(request, paginate={"per_page": 5}).configure(books_table)

    return render(request, 'publisher_show.html',
                  {'publisher': publisher,
                   'books_table': books_table,
                   'books_qs': books_qs})
else:
    messages.info(request, "Publisher does not exist")
    return publishers(request)
```

authors_show.html

```
{% load django_tables2 %}

{% load xextends  %}

{% load has_group %}

<!--"base.html" with active_tab=books small_panel=true center_panel_content=true-->

{% block content %}

<div class="page-title-outer"><div class="page-title">{{ author.name|title }} {{ author.surname|title }}</div></div>
<div class="book_desc">

    Name: {{ author.name }}<br/>


    Surname: {{ author.surname }}<br/>

    Date of birth: {{ author.date_of_birth }}<br/>



</div>
    {# List books by this author #}
    {% if books_qs.count > 0 %}
    {% autoescape off %}
    {% render_table books_table "table_without_footer.html" %}
    {% endautoescape %}
    {% endif %}

<a href="{% url 'authors' %}">List of authors</a><br/><br/>

{% if request.user|has_group:"librarians" %}
    <ul>
        <li><a href="{% url 'edit' 'authors' author.id %}">Edit</a> this author</li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'remove' 'authors' author.id %}"
               onclick='return confirm("Do you really want to delete author: {{ author.name }} {{ author.surname }}?")'>Remove
        </a> this author</li>
    </ul>
{% else %}

{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

has_group.py

```
from django import template

from django.contrib.auth.models import Group


register = template.Library()


@register.filter(is_safe=True)

@register.filter(name='librarians')
def has_group(user, librarians):
"""
Checks if user belongs to certain group
"""
group = Group.objects.get(name=librarians)
return True if group in user.groups.all() else False


register.filter('librarians', has_group)
```

error occured:

```
 File "/home/divum/PycharmProjects/untitled2/librarymanage/library/templatetags/has_group.py", line 14, in has_group
group = Group.objects.get(name=librarians)

 File "/home/divum/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

 File "/home/divum/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 380, in get
self.model._meta.object_name

DoesNotExist: Group matching query does not exist.

[04/Mar/2019 12:38:43] "GET /library/authors/show/3/ HTTP/1.1" 500 161171

 Request Method:    GET
 Request URL:   http://localhost:8000/library/periods/show/2/
 Django Version:    1.11.20
 Exception Type:    TemplateSyntaxError
 Exception Value:   
 Invalid filter: 'has_group'
 Exception Location:     
 /home/divum/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site- 
  packages/django/template/base.py in parse, line 515
   Python Executable:    
   /home/divum/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/bin/python2.7
  Python Version:   2.7.14
```

Comment: The error occured in  `has_group.py` Please add it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] as no one will analyse your whole code for the error.